# Jenkins build trigger not showing

Tags: jenkins

I've installed jenkins server on my aws ec2 instance.

And I've added a new item on jenkins.

I wanted build trigger "Build when a change is pushed to Github".

But as you can see, it doesn't not showing. It's weired.

Am I missing something?

I've already installed git plugin.

Any opinion would be appreciated.
TIA.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature was renamed from "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" to "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling". Instructions for hooking it up are at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin.

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed it's a duplicated question. I got it. Thanks a lot!!